# Send json data from android to php linux server

Tags: java, php, android, json, linux

I developed a Android app that sends data to a php web-service, using JSON. I did it using wampp server, and everything was going ok. But now, I'm trying to deploy it in a web hosting with Linux sever (GoDaddy.com), and weird things is happen now.

Here is my java code:

```
URL url = new URL(JSON_POST_VENDA);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                // To upload data to a web server, configure the connection for output
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                // For best performance, you should call either setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int)
                // when the body length is known in advance, or setChunkedStreamingMode(int)
                // when it is not
                con.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

                con.setRequestMethod("POST");

                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                con.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");

                // bla bla bla ... (just adding JSONObject and array)

                os = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "utf-8");
                os.write(vendaJson.toString());
                os.close();

                if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String sLinha = null;
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((sLinha = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        builder.append(sLinha+"\n");
                    }
                    reader.close();

                    Log.d("Post da Venda", builder.toString());

                    return builder.toString();
                } else {
                    Log.d("Post de Venda", "Não conseguiu conectar!");
                    return "500";
                }
```

And my php server code:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  //primeiro parametro recupera o objeto json do post content
  //segundo parametro transforma o objeto em array assossiativo
  //$jsondata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

  $param = file_get_contents("php://input");
  echo "Receved: ".$param;

  $jsondata = json_decode($param, true);
  $json_errors = array(
    JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
    JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
    JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
    JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
);
 echo 'Last error : ', $json_errors[json_last_error()], PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
```

What logged in "Log.d("Post da Venda", builder.toString());" line was:

D/Post da Venda: Receved: Last error : No error has occurred

I'm sure the server is working, beacause I've tested it using JaSON for Chrome, and got this response:

Receved: {"vl_liquido":130,"piercer":6,"produtos":[{"vl_liquido":120,"produto":7,"vl_desconto":0,"vl_unitario":120,"qtd":1,"descricao":"Barbell Ouro Amarelo 2mm Ouro ","vl_total":120}],"idvenda":0,"servicos":[{"vl_liquido":10,"servico":2,"vl_desconto":0,"vl_unitario":10,"qtd":1,"descricao":"Aplicação Piercing Nariz","vl_total":10}],"vl_bruto":130,"data":"2016-03-05","funcionario":7,"tt_itens":2,"vl_desconto":0,"senha":5,"observacao":""}Last error : No error has occurred

What can be happening?
I've seached fro chatset casting, but nothing worked for me.

Any help would be apreciated,

Thank you

Comment: So what is going wrong? Your server doesn't receive the json data or what? Because the `Log.d()` you specified only gets called when you get a HTTP status 200 which indicates the request was received by the server without errors.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp, yes the server doesn't receive the data. The $param variable is empty in echo call. I'm sugin php version 5.5 (just a info).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fix this problem by using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). It's very simple to implement.

Thanks for everything.